# How can I add my Token symbol image in the Smart Contract?

Tags: tokens

I have noticed that for some token contract, it comes with a symbol image along with the token symbol name. How can I upload a token symbol image together with my ERC20 contract? Thanks a lot

https://etherscan.io/address/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52

[image: BNB Token Symbol Image Logo]